# BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED undefined

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new (to android) and I am coding a bluetooth devices scan using a freshly installed Eclipse Kepler.
on the second of the following lines:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
```

I get a build error: **ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED cannot be resolved or is not a field**.

Please note that the first line is ok, so I am presuming to have imported the right stuff.
My application manifest has the following
    android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Of course I can survive somehow without ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED using isDiscovering(), but I would like to know why I don't have this constant defined in my android.jar
Can somebody help me in explaining this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct call should be:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
```

Using ***BluetoothAdapter*** instead of BluetoothDevice.

ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED is a property of the BluetoothAdapter class and isn't defined for BluetoothDevice. Give that a try?